# Loop through Json, search for same key endings, delete key ending and put it in new objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I got a `json` from my database. I want two create a new object from this `json`. I want find all keys with the same ending and put it to a new object. The key endings can be different and morein other jsons from my database. I want also to delete this ending. Please see my example

This is my `json`:

```
   {
          "QMSI1_EndingTwo": "Anaesthetist",
          "QMSI2_EndingTwo": "1899-12-30  15:36:57",
          "QMSI3_EndingTwo": "1899-12-30 17:32:00",
          "QMSI4_EndingTwo": "note1",
          "QMSI5_EndingTwo": "ivf",
          "QMSI1_EndingOne": "Small culture bowl",
          "QMSI5_EndingOne": "lucas"
       }
```

i want this result:

```
 [{
    "QMSI1": "Anaesthetist",
    "QMSI2": "1899-12-30  15:36:57",
    "QMSI3": "1899-12-30 17:32:00",
    "QMSI4": "note1",
    "QMSI5": "ivf"
  },
  {
    "QMSI1": "Small culture bowl",
    "QMSI5": "lucas"
  }]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.reduce` to group the values in an object having keys as the "beginnings" that you get from splitting the key, then extract the `Object.values` :

```js
const data = {
  QMSI1_EndingTwo: "Anaesthetist",
  QMSI2_EndingTwo: "1899-12-30  15:36:57",
  QMSI3_EndingTwo: "1899-12-30 17:32:00",
  QMSI4_EndingTwo: "note1",
  QMSI5_EndingTwo: "ivf",
  QMSI1_EndingOne: "Small culture bowl",
  QMSI5_EndingOne: "lucas"
};

const resultObj = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  const [k, ending] = key.split("_");

  acc[ending] = acc[ending] || {};

  acc[ending][k] = value;

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(resultObj).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i have added the result, this looks like a good way. any idea to get it like i need it as described above ?

Comment: the result looks like that :

[ [ { QMSI1: 'Anaesthetist' },
    { QMSI2: '1899-12-30  15:36:57' },
    { QMSI3: '1899-12-30 17:32:00' },
    { QMSI4: 'note1' },
    { QMSI5: 'ivf' } ],
  [ { QMSI1: 'Small culture bowl' }, { QMSI5: 'lucas' } ] ]

but i need the object like in the example above

Comment: nice solution, it works exactly as i need it thx a lot <3
Can you quick explain what this curly braces are for?    "  return acc;
}, {}); "

Comment: @JosefHenn it's the initial value of the accumulator, the value that `reduce` will start from, in this case `{}` is an empty object.

Comment: perfect now i get it, again nice answer !